# D3: Creating colored curve line chart joining points

Tags: javascript, d3.js, curve

I created a line graph in D3, with segments of different colors (blue for a segment above 0 and red below 0). But I would like to make it a curved line instead of a straight line, and I also would like to color the line blue when it's above the 0 value of the X axis and red when it's below. I don't seem to be able to do this though. This is my code. Can anyone help?

https://codepen.io/Ruben-Gomez-the-typescripter/pen/ExGOQqo

Javascript

```js
const data = [];
data.push({ date: "2023-10-04", pnl: 0 });
data.push({ date: "2023-10-05", pnl: 800 });
data.push({ date: "2023-10-06", pnl: -1000 });
data.push({ date: "2023-10-07", pnl: 400 });

// Parse the date strings into JavaScript Date objects
const parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
data.forEach(function (d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
});

// Sort trades by date
data.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.date - b.date;
});

let cumulativePnl = 0;
data.forEach((d) => {
  cumulativePnl += d.pnl;
  d.cumulativePnl = cumulativePnl;
});



// Set up the SVG element
const svg = d3.select("#performanceChart"),
  margin = { top: 20, right: 70, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

svg.selectAll("*").remove(); // This line clears all child elements of the SVG

// Create a group element for the chart and position it based on the margins
const g = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Find the absolute maximum value in the data (ignoring sign)
const absMaxValue = d3.max(data, function (d) {
  return Math.abs(d.cumulativePnl);
});

// Set up the scales based on your data
const xScale = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width]);
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

xScale.domain(
  d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return d.date;
  })
);
yScale.domain([-absMaxValue, absMaxValue]); // Set the Y domain to be symmetrical around 0

// add some padding so the curve does not touch the axis
const xPadding = 10;
xScale.rangeRound([0 + xPadding, width - xPadding]);

const yPadding = 16;
yScale.rangeRound([height - yPadding, 0 + yPadding]);

// Extract the dates from your data
// const dates = data.map(function(d) { return d.date; });

// Append the X Axis
g.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(
    d3.axisBottom(xScale.copy().interpolate(d3.interpolateRound)).tickSize(0)
  )
  .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove())
  .call((g) =>
    g
      .selectAll(".tick line")
      .clone()
      .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.1)
      .attr("y1", -height)
  );

// Append the Y Axis
g.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale.copy().interpolate(d3.interpolateRound)).tickSize(0))
  .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove())
  .call((g) =>
    g
      .selectAll(".tick line")
      .clone()
      .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.1)
      .attr("x1", width)
  );

// Create the line generator function
let line = d3
  .line()
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX) // This ensures the line will have a curved interpolation
  .x((d) => xScale(d.date))
  .y((d) => yScale(d.cumulativePnl));

function lineColor(d) {
  return d.cumulativePnl >= 0 ? "steelblue" : "red";
}

for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  g.append("path")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", lineColor(data[i]))
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2.5)
    .attr("d", line([data[i - 1], data[i]]));
}

// tooltip
const tooltip = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "chart-tooltip")
  .style("position", "absolute")
  .style("background-color", "white")
  .style("padding", "5px")
  .style("border", "1px solid #ccc")
  .style("border-radius", "5px")
  .style("opacity", "0");

// add a mouse over area
g.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "overlay")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("pointer-events", "all")
  .on("mouseover", mouseover)
  .on("mousemove", mousemove)
  .on("mouseout", mouseout);

const bisectDate = d3.bisector(function (d) {
  return d.date;
}).left;
const formatValue = d3.format(",.2f");
const formatDate = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d");

function mouseover() {
  tooltip.style("opacity", 1);
}

function mousemove(event) {
  if (trades.length == 0) return;

  const x0 = xScale.invert(d3.pointer(event)[0]);
  const i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1);
  const d0 = data[i - 1];
  const d1 = data[i];

  // Safety check: If d1 does not exist, use d0 as the selected data point
  let d;
  if (d1) {
    d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
  } else {
    d = d0;
  }

  // Determine the color for the focus point
  const focusColor = d.cumulativePnl <= 0 ? "red" : "steelblue";

  // Position the focus dot over the data point
  focus
    .attr("cx", xScale(d.date))
    .attr("cy", yScale(d.cumulativePnl))
    .style("fill", focusColor) // Set the fill color
    .style("stroke", focusColor) // Set the stroke color
    .style("display", null); // Make the dot visible

  tooltip
    .style("left", event.pageX + 5 + "px")
    .style("top", event.pageY - 28 + "px")
    .html(
      `<strong>Date:</strong> ${formatDate(
        d.date
      )}<br><strong>Daily PnL:</strong> ${formatValue(
        d.pnl
      )}$<br><strong>Cumulative PnL:</strong> ${formatValue(d.cumulativePnl)}$`
    );
}

function mouseout() {
  tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
  focus.style("display", "none");
}

// focus point
const focus = g
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 4.5) // You can adjust the radius as needed
  // .style("fill", "#3D3D44")
  // .style("stroke", "#3D3D44") // Color of the dot
  .style("display", "none"); // Initially hidden

// Get the last data point
const lastDataPoint = data[data.length - 1];

// Append text element to show the last value of cumulativePnl
g.append("text")
  .attr("x", xScale(lastDataPoint.date) + 5) // Small offset to place it to the right of the line end
  .attr("y", yScale(lastDataPoint.cumulativePnl))
  .attr("dy", "-0.3em") // Slightly shift the text up
  .attr("font-weight", "bold") // This line makes the text bold
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("fill", lastDataPoint.cumulativePnl >= 0 ? "steelblue" : "red") // Color code based on value
  .text(`${lastDataPoint.cumulativePnl.toFixed(2)}$`);
```

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
<body>
  <div id="performanceContainer">
    <svg id="performanceChart" width="950" height="550"></svg>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>

</html>
```